# VBA Error: Runtime Error: 9 - Subscript out of range when copying a worksheet from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am generating a new workbook from a multiple workbooks, i can generate a summary of all the errors found, but when i try to copy the sheets with the error information i got the runtime error 9

These is the line failing

```
                    If exists = True Then
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    End If
```

Other thing i havent add is that all the sheets on the multiple files have the same names, so i want to know if there is a way that the sheet when is copy i can add the file name and the sheet name

```
Sub getViolations()
Path = "C:\Users\omartinr\Desktop\New folder (4)\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set TxtRng = ws.Range("A1:N1")
    TxtRng.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    TxtRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    TxtRng.Value = [{"Partition Name","Tag","EM Supply","SH Signal","PK","Sfactor","FiSH","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL"}]
    TxtRng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        Dim wc As Worksheet
        Set wc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")

        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary").Range("B1")
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary").Range("C1")


        Dim count As Integer
        count = 15
        Dim sheetName As String, mySheetNameTest As String
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim exits As Boolean

        For n = 3 To 14

            If Not IsEmpty(wc.Cells(n, 2)) Then

                If (wc.Cells(n, 2)) = 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 4
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)

                End If
                If (wc.Cells(n, 2)) > 0 Then


                    Select Case wc.Cells(n, 1)

                    Case "PK"
                       sheetName = "Peak"
                    Case "Sfactor"
                        sheetName = "SF Supply"
                    Case Else
                       sheetName = wc.Cells(n, 1)
                    End Select
                    exists = sheetExists(sheetName)
                    If exists = True Then
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    End If

                    ws.Cells(i, count) = wc.Cells(1, n).Value
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)

                End If
                If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary").Cells(n, 2)) < 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)

                End If

            End If

            If IsEmpty(wc.Cells(n, 2)) Then
                ws.Cells(i, n).Value = ["NA"]
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next n

        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub


Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

Comment: why are you making us guess which line causes the error?  do you think that it is un-important information?

Comment: you define `wc` here `Set wc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")`, but in the next two lines you do not use `wc`, you use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")`. why is that? ... actually, you do the same thing a third time further down.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry is late forgot to put the line failing in other part, i already show the part that is giving me the error, and forgot to put that the worksheet is save in the new workbook, but when it happens script show the error

Comment: you actually posted 3 lines as failing ... is it the `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` ?

Comment: tip: instead of these two lines `exists = sheetExists(sheetName)` `If exists = True Then` .... use `If sheetExists(sheetName) Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put option explicit at top so spelling of variables is checked and that they are declared. The variable exists was mispelt and there were a number of other variables not declared. I have put some other comments in with the code.

Some of the logic i think can be simplified and i have given some examples. Also, ensure consistent use of named variable wc. If nothing else it should be easier to debug now. Compiles on my machine so give it a try.

This all works on the assumption that each workbook you open has the "Violations Summary" sheet and it is spelt as shown.

You have the filename already stored in the variable Filename so you can use (concatenate?) that with the sheetname variable.

```
Option Explicit 'Set this to ensure all variable declared and consistent spelling
'Consider using WorkSheets collection rather than Sheets unless you have chart sheets as well?
Sub getViolations()
    Dim Path As String 'Declare you other variables
    Dim FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Users\omartinr\Desktop\New folder (4)\New folder\"
    FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TxtRng As Range 'Declare this
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set TxtRng = ws.Range("A1:N1")
    TxtRng.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    TxtRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    TxtRng.Value = [{"Partition Name","Tag","EM Supply","SH Signal","PK","Sfactor","FiSH","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL"}]
    TxtRng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2

    Do While FileName <> ""

        Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True

        Dim wc As Worksheet 'Consider whether to place these declarations just before the loop, avoids risk others may think there will be reinitialization even though there isn't

        Set wc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = wc.Range("B1") 'Use the wc variable
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = wc.Range("C1")

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim sheetName As String, mySheetNameTest As String
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim exists As Boolean 'Corrected spelling

        count = 15

        For n = 3 To 14

            If Not IsEmpty(wc.Cells(n, 2)) Then

                If (wc.Cells(n, 2)) = 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 4
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)
                End If

                If (wc.Cells(n, 2)) > 0 Then

                    Select Case wc.Cells(n, 1)
                        Case "PK"
                            sheetName = "Peak"
                        Case "Sfactor"
                           sheetName = "SF Supply"
                        Case Else
                          sheetName = wc.Cells(n, 1)
                    End Select

                    exists = sheetExists(sheetName)

                    If exists Then  'Shortened by removing = True (evaluates in same way)
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    End If

                    ws.Cells(i, count) = wc.Cells(1, n).Value
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)

                End If

                If (wc.Cells(n, 2)) < 0 Then 'used wc variable
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws.Cells(i, n).Value = wc.Cells(n, 2)
                End If

            Else  'Simplified this as if is not empty then is empty so can use else
                ws.Cells(i, n).Value = ["NA"] 'what is pupose of square brackets? These can be removed i think
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next n

        Workbooks(FileName).Close
        FileName = Dir()
    i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub


Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet ' declare
    sheetExists = False

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After you copy the `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)` to `ThisWorkbook`, `ThisWorkbook` becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`.  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` should not throw an error but will probably cause `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")` to fail.  For this reason, you should always fully qualify your references.

Some idealist programmers say that a subroutine should perform 1 simply task.  Personally, I believe that if you have to scroll up, down, left or right to see what your code is doing it is time to refactor it.  When refactoring I try to extract logical groups of tasks in a separate subroutine.   This makes debugging and modifying the code far easier.

### Refactored Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub getViolations()
    Const Path As String = "C:\Users\omartinr\Desktop\New folder (4)\New folder\"
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Sheet1Setup ws
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        ProcessWorkbook Filename, ws.Rows(n)
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub ProcessWorkbook(WBName As String, row As Range)
    Dim nOffset As Long, n As Long
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    With WB.Sheets("Violations Summary")
        row.Columns(1).Value = .Range("B1")
        row.Columns(2).Value = .Range("C1")
        nOffset = 12
        For n = 3 To 14
            If .Cells(n, 2) = "" Then
                row.Columns(n).Value = ["NA"]
            ElseIf (.Cells(n, 2)) = 0 Then
                row.Columns(n).Font.ColorIndex = 4
                row.Columns(n).Font.ColorIndex = 0
            ElseIf (.Cells(n, 2)) = 0 Then
                Select Case wc.Cells(n, 1)
                    Case "PK"
                        sheetName = "Peak"
                    Case "Sfactor"
                        sheetName = "SF Supply"
                    Case Else
                        sheetName = wc.Cells(n, 1)
                End Select
                'Range.Parent refers to the ranges worksheet.  row.Parent refers to ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                If SheetExists(WB, sheetName) Then .Copy After:=row.Parent.Sheets(1)
                row.Columns(n + nOffset) = .Cells(1, n).Value
                row.Columns(n).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                row.Columns(n).Value = .Cells(n, 2)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Function SheetExists(WB As Workbook, sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In WB.Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = ws.Name Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Sheet1Setup(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.Range("A1:N1")
        .Value = [{"Partition Name","Tag","EM Supply","SH Signal","PK","Sfactor","FiSH","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL","RESCAL"}]
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

Note:  `row` is the target Row of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`.  `row.Columns(3)` is a fancy way to write `row.Cells(1, 3)` which refers to the 3rd cell in the target row.  Also note that Cells, Columns, and Rows are all relative to the range they belong to. e.g. `Range("C1").Columns(2)` refers to `D1`, `Range("C1").Rows(2).Columns(2)` refers to `D2`, `Range("C1").Cells(2,2)` also refers to `D2`.